# List Constructor: How does it really work in the following code?

Tags: python, data-structures

```
thislist = list(("apple", "banana", "cherry"))
thislist = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
```

In terms of

- List class
- List object
- List constructor

I would like to understand how exactly does the above code function and create the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `list` and `tuple` are both built in python classes.

## Let's first talk about `Lists`

Lists are sequences and are used to store collections of homogeneous items.

The list constructor is:

```
list([iterable])
```

You can construct List in several ways:

- With a pair of square brackets which denotes the empty list. For Example: `[]`
- With square brackets and items separated with commas. For Example: `[a, b, c]`
- With the help of a list comprehension. For Example: `[x for x in iterable]`
- With the help of type constructor. For Example: `list()` or `list(iterable)`

> The **constructor** `list(iterable)` builds a list whose items are the same and in the same order as iterable’s items.

Here, `iterable` may be either a sequence or an object that supports iteration, or an iterator object.

If `iterable` is already a list: *A copy of the list is returned*

For example:

```
>>> list('abc') 
['a', 'b', 'c'] 
>>> list( (1, 2, 3) ) # Next let's understand what a tuple is
[1, 2, 3]
```

## Now let's talk about `Tuples`

Tuples are sequences which are used to store collections of heterogeneous data.

The tuple constructor is:

```
tuple([iterable])
```

You can create tuples in many ways:

- With a pair of parentheses to denote the empty tuple. For Example: `()`
- With many items separated by commas. For Example: `(a, b, c)`
- With a trailing comma for a singleton tuple. For Example: `a,` or `(a,)`
- With the help of `tuple()` constructor. For Example: `tuple()` or `tuple(iterable)`

This `tuple(iterable)` constructor builds a tuple with identical items and in same order as iterable’s items. The `iterable` can be a sequence or an iterator object.

If `iterable` is already a tuple it's copy will be returned. 
For Example:

```
>>> tuple('abc') 
('a', 'b', 'c') 
>>> tuple( [1, 2, 3] ) 
(1, 2, 3)
>>> tuple
()
>>> t = 1,2,3
>>> t
(1, 2, 3)
```

> Note that it is actually the comma which makes a tuple, not the parentheses. The parentheses are optional, except in the empty tuple case, or when they are needed to avoid syntactic ambiguity.

### Taking your question as an example:

> You want to give a tuple to create a list. So to identify that the input to the list constructor is a tuple it is need to be enclosed in parentheses.

```
thislist = list(("apple", "banana", "cherry"))
```

Here `("apple", "banana", "cherry")` will create a tuple implicitly. Then this tuple `("apple", "banana", "cherry")` is the `iterable` input for the `list` constructor and returns an list object.

```
>>> type(("apple", "banana", "cherry"))
<class 'tuple'>
```

When you provide `["apple", "banana", "cherry"]`, an object of list is created implicitly and returned.

```
>>> type(["apple", "banana", "cherry"])
<class 'list'>
```

Answer (score 1):

`list` is a built-in class in Python. There are three main ways of constructing a list.

The first way is by calling the "constructor", or `list.__call__`, usually with `list(...)`. The constructor accepts any iterable and initializes a list that refers to all of its elements. In your first example, you pass in the `tuple` of strings `("apple", "banana", "cherry")`. The result of the assignment is that a new list object is bound to the name `thislist`.

The second way is by enclosing a comma-separated collection in square brackets. The result of `thislist = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]` is that a new list object equal to the one in the first example is bound to the name `thislist`. This notation is possible because the type `list` is so integral to the Python language that the interpreter recognizes this syntax. Other examples of similarly fundamental data structure types are `set` (initialized by `{'a', 'b', 'c'}`), `dict` (initialized by `{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}`) and `tuple` (initialized by `('a', 'b', 'c')`).

The third way to construct a list is through a comprehension. It's sort of a hybrid of the first two ways because it allows you to use an iterable, rather than a literal sequence, inside square brackets. An example of a list comprehension would be something like:

```
thislist = [x for x in ("apple", "banana", "cherry")]
```

In general, a comprehension works by constructing an empty list and appending the elements of the generator expression in the brackets. It's roughly equivalent to

```
thislist = []  # or thislist = list()
for x in ("apple", "banana", "cherry"):
    thislist.append(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

List is a built-in python iterator:

This will initiate a new empty list:

> this_list = list() -> this_list is now a list object

This will create a new list initialized from iterable's items

> this_list = list(iterable) -> List 'this_list' is being constructed using list constructor

For ex:

> this_tuple = ("apple", "banana", "cherry")

To convert this tuple into list one would use:

```
>>> this_list = list(this_tuple)

>>> this_list

["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
```